# Show $ab=ba$, if $a, b\in G$ and $(m,n)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We are given a group $G$ and $m$, $n$ co-prime. We need to show that if $a,b\in G$  and $a^m b^m= b^m a^m$ and $a^n b^n = b^n a^n$ holds then $ab=ba$.

I tried to work around by showing that there exists $x,y$ such that $mx+ny=1$ and I tried to write $a^{mx} b a^{ny}=b^{mx} a b^{ny}$. I am stuck here, I am not able to proceed. Any hints/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track! Take $x,y$ such that $mx+ny=1$. Then $$ab=a^{mx+ny}b^{mx+ny}=a^{mx}a^{ny}b^{mx}b^{ny}=a^{ny}a^{mx}b^{mx}b^{ny}=a^{ny}(a^m)^x(b^m)^xb^{ny}.$$
Your assumptions give you that $(a^m)^x(b^m)^x=(b^m)^x(a^m)^x$ (why?). Now you can finish to unravel the equalities above to get $ab=ba$.

**EDIT:** This is wrong! The "unraveling" part doesn't get anywhere. See the comments. For a counterexample, see David Hill's answer.

Comment: The part you ask why, is the one I was having difficulty to get to. But yes, now I can with induction. Do you know a simpler way.

Comment: Yes, induction is a good way to prove the "why". I can't think of a better way to prove this right now, but there probably is one, my argument being not very elegant.

Comment: If $a^m b^m = b^m a^m$, raise both sides to the $x$ power, such that $(a^m)^x(b^m)^x=(b^m)^x(a^m)^x$

Comment: I'm sorry, the bit you left to unravel is beyond me.

Comment: $a^{ny}a^{mx}b^{mx}b^{ny}=a^{ny}b^{mx}a^{mx}b^{ny}$, what next? Hypothesis looks not sufficient.

Comment: Wow, indeed I went a bit too fast. Thanks for pointing that out. If the OP returs here, please accept David Hill's answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 4):

This statement is false for $S_3$. Take $a=(123)$ and $b=(12)$. Then $a^3b^3=b=b^3a^3$ and $a^2b^2=a^2=b^2a^2$. But $ab=ba^{-1}\neq ba$.